# mongoose-paginate with react and material-ui TablePagination - second page onwards not rendering after clicking of onChangePage prop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, material-ui

I am relatively new to React, and in this React component I must be missing something basic. Will greatly appreciate any guidance towards the solution.

**Functionlaity I am trying to achieve here** - Implementing a pagination with [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) in the backend and Material-UI **[TablePagination](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/)** in the front-end. So each time, the user clicks on the next-page icon (a forward or backward arrow) there will be a database call with axios.get and data will be fetched from mongo and rendered in a table in the UI.

To achieve this, I have  the handleChangePage() function in React whcih will invoke the axios.get function.

**The issue** - From the second page onwards data are not rendeiring, but with console.log, I can see (in the chrome-devtool) that the data were indeed fetched from backend after clicking on the next page icon. But that fetched data is not getting rendered in the UI.

This is the React code in my rendering component. The key function is **handleChangePage()** , this is where I do the database call to fetch the data each time, user clicks on the next page icon (next page icon is that of Material-UI **TablePagination** component)

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allDevelopmentWorks: [],
      allDevelopmentWorksFormatted: [],      
      selected: [],
      page: 0,
      rowsPerPage: 5,      
      renderOnlyDateRangeData: false,
      developmentWorksDateRange: []
    };
  }

  // Function to handle the the request from user to sort by a particular heading.
  handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = "desc";

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === "desc") {
      order = "asc";
    }    
    this.setState({ order, orderBy });
  };

  handleSelectAllClick = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        selected: state.allDevelopmentWorks.map(n => n._id)
      }));
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  };

  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }
    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/developmenties/")
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(
          {
            allDevelopmentWorksFormatted: res.data
          },
          () => {
            this.state.allDevelopmentWorksFormatted.map((item, index) => {
              if (item.date_of_commencement || item.date_of_completion) {
                this.state.allDevelopmentWorksFormatted[
                  index
                ].date_of_commencement =
                  moment(item.date_of_commencement).format(
                    "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
                  ) + `AM`;
                this.state.allDevelopmentWorksFormatted[
                  index
                ].date_of_completion =
                  moment(item.date_of_completion).format(
                    "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
                  ) + `AM`;
              }
            });
          }
        );
      })
      .then(
        axios
          .get("/api/developmenties/paginate", {
            params: {
              page: this.state.page,
              rowsperpage: this.state.rowsPerPage
            }
          })
          .then(res => {
            console.log("THE RESPONSE FOR PAGINATION IS ", res.data);
            this.setState({
              allDevelopmentWorks: res.data
            });
          })
      )
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (

       this.state.developmentWorksDateRange.length !==
    prevState.developmentWorksDateRange.length ||
  this.state.allDevelopmentWorksFormatted.length !==
    prevState.allDevelopmentWorksFormatted.length ||
  this.state.rowsPerPage !== prevState.rowsPerPage

    ) {
      return axios
        .get("/api/developmenties/paginate", {
          params: {
            page: this.state.page,
            rowsperpage: this.state.rowsPerPage
          }
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            allDevelopmentWorks: res.data
          });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }


  handleChangePage = async (event, page) => {
    // console.log("THIS PAGE NO IS ", page);
    await this.setState({ page });
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/developmenties/paginate`, {
      params: {
        page: page,
        rowsperpage: this.state.rowsPerPage
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      allDevelopmentWorks: res.data
    });    
  };

  handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
    this.setState({ rowsPerPage: event.target.value });
  };

  isSelected = id => this.state.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

  unSelectItems = () => {
    this.setState({
      selected: []
    });
  };

  handleQueryString = queryTypedInChild => {
    this.setState({
      queryStringFromChild: queryTypedInChild
    });
  };

  handleColumnToQuery = columnToQueryInChild => {
    this.setState({
      columnToQuery: columnToQueryInChild
    });
  };

  clearAllQueryString = () => {
    this.setState({
      queryStringFromChild: "",
      columnToQuery: "location"
    });
  };

  ifUserWantsDateRangeData = dateRangeArr => {
    this.setState({
      developmentWorksDateRange: [...dateRangeArr]
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const {
      order,
      orderBy,
      selected,
      rowsPerPage,
      page,
      allDevelopmentWorks,
      developmentWorksDateRange,
      allDevelopmentWorksFormatted,
      queryStringFromChild
    } = this.state;


    const emptyRows =
      rowsPerPage -
      Math.min(rowsPerPage, allDevelopmentWorks.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    // in below the whole table header is a different component 'EnhancedTableHead'
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col xs="12">
              {console.log(
                "CURRENT DEVELOPMENT LIST RENDERED IS  ",
                allDevelopmentWorks
              )}

              <Paper className={classes.root}>                
                <Table className={classes.table}>                  
                  <TableBody>
                    {stableSort(
                      allDevelopmentWorks,
                      getSorting(order, orderBy)
                    )
                      .slice(
                        page * rowsPerPage,
                        page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage
                      )
                      .map(n => {
                        const isSelected = this.isSelected(n._id);
                        return (
                          <TableRow
                            hover
                            onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n._id)}
                            role="checkbox"
                            aria-checked={isSelected}
                            tabIndex={-1}
                            key={n._id}
                            selected={isSelected}
                          >
                            <CustomTableCell padding="checkbox">
                              <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                            </CustomTableCell>
                            <CustomTableCell
                              component="th"
                              scope="row"
                              padding="none"
                            >
                              {n.location}
                            </CustomTableCell>
                            <CustomTableCell align="right">
                              {n.work_description}
                            </CustomTableCell>
                            <CustomTableCell align="right">
                              {moment(n.date_of_commencement).format(
                                "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
                              )}{" "}
                              {`AM`}
                            </CustomTableCell>
                            <CustomTableCell align="right">
                              {moment(n.date_of_completion).format(
                                "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
                              )}{" "}
                              {`AM`}
                            </CustomTableCell>
                            <CustomTableCell align="right">
                              {n.status_of_work}
                            </CustomTableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        );
                      })}
                    {emptyRows > 0 && (
                      <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                        <CustomTableCell colSpan={6} />
                      </TableRow>
                    )}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>                
                <TablePagination
                  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                  component="div"
                  count={allDevelopmentWorksFormatted.length}
                  rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                  page={page}
                  backIconButtonProps={{
                    "aria-label": "Previous Page"
                  }}
                  nextIconButtonProps={{
                    "aria-label": "Next Page"
                  }}
                  onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
                  onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
              </Paper>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <br />
          </Row>          
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

List.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(List);
```

As far as I could figure out, the source of the problem is the **handleChangePage()** function in handling the two setState within this.  The first setstate **this.setState({ page })** is firing a re-render and making my list re-render with the ONLY current data (i.e. before the next axios.get request within this function gets fired and update the variable  **allDevelopmentWorks**)

```
handleChangePage = async (event, page) => {       
    await this.setState({ page });
    await axios
      .get(`/api/developmenties/paginate`, {
        params: {
          page: this.state.page,
          rowsperpage: this.state.rowsPerPage
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          allDevelopmentWorks: res.data
        });
        console.log(
          "AFTER SETSTATE UPDATED ALL-DEVELOPMENTWORKS IS ",
          this.state.allDevelopmentWorks
        );
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

So, I tried to stop the re-render of the component after only the `this.setState({ page })` with the following code - BUT DID NOT RESOLVE MY ISSUE

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.page !== nextState.page) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

And the below is my backend routing code in Express to fetch data from mongo database. Development is the name of my mongoose schema.

```
// To GET ALL DevelopmentWorks - max 5 or 10 or 15 at a time (determined by whatever users sets it to be at the front-end MAT-UI)

router.get("/paginate", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("THE REQ.QUERY FOR PAGINATION IS ", req.query);
  let pageOptions = {
    page: parseInt(req.query.page) || 0,
    limit: parseInt(req.query.rowsperpage) || 5
  };

  if (req.query.page && req.query.rowsperpage) {
    Development.paginate(
      {},
      {
        offset: pageOptions.page * pageOptions.limit,
        limit: pageOptions.limit
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          next(err);
        } else {
          res.status(200).json(result.docs);
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

// To GET ALL DevelopmentWorks
router.route("/").get((req, res, next) => {
  Development.find(
    {},
    null,
    {
      sort: { createdAt: -1 }
    },
    (err, docs) => {
      // Development.find({ port: req.body.port._id }, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(docs);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Further notes - When I was NOT using **mongoose-paginate** and was loading the whole data (fetching it in a single call to the database ) then the **TablePaginaton** was working properly. But now to implement, the pagination, I want to make a new server call each time the user clicks on the next-page icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, after I fixed the issue. The problem was I was slicing the data to render in table two times. So, with mongoose-paginate integrated, the slicing job was done by the backend itself as mongoose-paginate would only send the sliced data to the front-end. But my mistake was that during the rendering of the table I was slicing again (as what was required when I was fetching the whole data at a single time before integrating mongoosse-paginate). Here's is the corrected portion of the above code (i.e. where I am rendeing the Table inside return() ).

```
<TableBody>
{stableSort(
  allDevelopmentWorks,
  getSorting(order, orderBy)
)
  .map(n => {
    const isSelected = this.isSelected(n._id);
    return (
      <TableRow
        hover
        onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n._id)}
        role="checkbox"
        aria-checked={isSelected}
        tabIndex={-1}
        key={n._id}
        selected={isSelected}
      >
        <CustomTableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
        </CustomTableCell>
        <CustomTableCell
          component="th"
          scope="row"
          padding="none"
        >
          {n.location}
        </CustomTableCell>
        <CustomTableCell align="right">
          {n.work_description}
        </CustomTableCell>
        <CustomTableCell align="right">
          {moment(n.date_of_commencement).format(
            "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
          )}{" "}
          {`AM`}
        </CustomTableCell>
        <CustomTableCell align="right">
          {moment(n.date_of_completion).format(
            "MMM D, YYYY 12:00:00 "
          )}{" "}
          {`AM`}
        </CustomTableCell>
        <CustomTableCell align="right">
          {n.status_of_work}
        </CustomTableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  })}
{emptyRows > 0 && (
  <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
    <CustomTableCell colSpan={6} />
  </TableRow>
)}
</TableBody>
```

I ONLY needed to delete the part

```
.slice(
          page * rowsPerPage,
          page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage
                      )
```

Comment: This worked for me, I removed the `.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)` in my TableBody in order to fix the server-side pagination. Thanks a lot!